# How can I send response from c# class file to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqldatareader

If my condition fails as `rdr.HasRows == true`, how can I respond my controller its fails

```
public Employee DeleteEmpById(int key)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetEmployeeById", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", key);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows == true)
        {
        }
        else
        // Here what I mention when rdr.HasRows false
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DeleteById(int id)
{
    var x = ObjRepo.DeleteEmpById(id);
    return View(x);
}
```

Comment: What do you do when its `true`. And why does your method return an `Instance` of `Employee` (which makes no sense if its deleted)? And [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And why is your method getting data when its name suggests it should be deleting data?

Comment: You could return `null` - or you could throw an exception .....

Comment: Please include the source code of `Sp_GetEmployeeById`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use While Read

```
 Bool HasData =False ;
 SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
 {
    // If there is A row  sqlDataReader Will read 
    HasData  =true ;
    break; // you only have to check one time ,  performance improve


 }



return HasData
```

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with the question.

Comment: someone changed the question  .simply he want to know  , Retrieve data or not

Comment: The only changes were to correct spelling errors and incorrect tags! `HasData` is a `bool` - OP methods returns `Employee` so this would just throw an exception! (in any case, the code in the question makes no sense)